# PHP how to maintain/update querystring across all links in page

Tags: php

I have a custom e-shop script written in PHP/MySQL. 
On the product pages there is a form using GET with a series of form elements (drop downs, check boxes, sliders etc) who's values are used to construct the final MySQL query for pulling the right products based on the users selections. To construct my query, I go through the $_GET array and construct it accordingly. But on the pages I also have pagination & sorting href links, a "Cancel this filter" href link under each option in the form to reset each form value etc.

My question is, how do I maintain the add the querystring to all links throughout the page so that the variables are maintained in any action (links, form submission, browser back-forth)?

Comment: Maybe have array of links in your init.php or core.php ore any other php script you are including on any page. For the links you judt nedd to echo e.g. `$links['product01']` This way you can have named links and all definitions in just one file!

Comment: How about show your pieces of code ..

Comment: The code is large, it's an entire e-shop script. The issue isn't code dependent, it's more about the logic and the best practices. Once I've understood what needs to be done I can do the coding.

Comment: I would use sessions for this tbh.

Comment: I am. But the question is specific to appending the querystring to all href links

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`http_build_query()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function with array of params that is changed accordingly to each link.

Comment: Ok, but how do I append the querystring to all links in the page?

Comment: You mean how to do it without changing any code? Like i.e. with JavaScript?

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure cause I dont know what all the options are.

Comment: How it works now? You have links hardcoded into your HTML markup or you use some sort of framework with functions to create links? I would recommend you using some function (view helper) to assemble link.

Comment: I'm not using a framework, it's a mix of PHP-HTML. Most links are hardcoded into the HTML. Also, the coding is in plain PHP, not some sort of MVC.